# Is a Harvard PhD in applied mathematics (from engr. dept.) as reputable as a PhD in pure mathematics (from math dept)?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school

Most rankings systems rank math at Harvard quite favorably. Is phd in applied mathematics (control theory) at Harvard as reputable as a phd in pure math at Harvard? (The first is offered in an engineering department while the second is offered in a math department)

Comment: Surely not to pure mathematicians.  Why don't you look at specialized rankings for applied math?

Comment: I don't see how pure mathematicians would have any say in this issue.

Comment: If you pay for the US News [graduate school rankings](https://www.usnews.com/usnews/store/grad_school_compass.htm), is there a ranking for "Applied Math"? I didn't pay, so I don't know.

Comment: @GEdgar: there's a lot of information you can get from US News graduate school rankings without paying. ["Applied Math"](https://www.usnews.com/best-graduate-schools/top-science-schools/applied-mathematics-rankings) is a subcategory of "Mathematics", and Harvard doesn't even make the top 14 (despite being in the top 4 for math).

Comment: lol, it is even harder to get in Harvard through applied math because only one or two students are taken each year.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I got my PhD at Harvard in mathematics.  Not in "pure math" but just in "math."  Harvard does not have an "applied mathematics" department or a "PhD program in applied mathematics."  Rather, applied mathematics is one of seven "areas of study" in the school of engineering and applied sciences: see [here](https://gsas.harvard.edu/programs-of-study/all/applied-math).  What does this mean?  Well, [see here](https://www.seas.harvard.edu/academics/graduate).  It says:

> In keeping with the interdisciplinary nature of modern research, we do not have traditional academic departments and do not award degrees by specific research area. Instead, graduate students work toward a degree in one of seven subjects—Applied Mathematics, Applied Physics, Computer Science, Computational Science & Engineering, Data Science, Design Engineering, and Engineering Sciences.

Some of these subjects have "PhD model programs," but when you click on applied math, [you find](https://www.seas.harvard.edu/academics/graduate/phd-model-programs/phd-model-program-applied-mathematics)

> Due to its highly interdisciplinary nature, Applied Mathematics does not have a specific model program.  Students pursuing a Ph.D. in Applied Mathematics should consult with their Director of Graduate Studies: Professor Ariel Amir (fall), or Professor Yue Lue (spring), concerning their degree programs.

Interestingly, Professor Amir is an Assistant Professor of Applied Mathematics.  [Interesting in part because the mathematics department has had only "full" professors for at least 20 years.]  Here is a [listing of faculty in applied mathematics](https://www.seas.harvard.edu/applied-mathematics/people) at Harvard: the only other professor who is listed as being solely in applied mathematics is also an assistant professor.  This suggests to me that applied math at Harvard may be in the process of becoming more of an academic department than it has been or is now.  The time would be ripe, in view of the [record $400 million gift of Mr. Paulson in 2015](http://www.thecrimson.com/article/2015/6/3/record-gift-paulson-seas/).

All that was mostly background.  Now I can tell you: when I was at Harvard (1998-2003) there was almost no direct contact between the mathematics department and the mathematics part of SEAS: I knew one SEAS PhD student who was (for some reason) teaching freshman calculus along with the math students.  (I just looked him up: he has what looks like a lucrative industry job in Boston.)  So the answer to your question is: **No one I know is comparing these two programs**. They are different in every way, with almost no overlap.  It's not as though you could choose to do control theory in the math department at Harvard: there is no one there that does that.  (There is one professor in the Harvard math department who does what I at least would call applied mathematics: [Martin Nowak, the Professor of Biology and Mathematics and Director of the Program for Evolutionary Dynamics](https://ped.fas.harvard.edu/martin_nowak).)

It would make more sense to compare the engineering program at Harvard to other engineering programs.  US News ranks Harvard's engineering program at #23 currently.  If you look at [this page](https://www.usnews.com/best-graduate-schools/harvard-university-166027/overall-rankings) it gives you the ranking of a variety of programs at Harvard, and actually it has the lowest rank of the more than 100 programs and subprograms listed there.  The math department is currently ranked third [it has been ranked in the top three for many years].  So maybe that is a sense in which "pure math is more reputable," although again I stress that this does not seem like the right way to look at it.

Comment: It seems to me you're saying that Harvard Math and Harvard Applied Math are like apples and oranges. The comparison between them doesn't make too much sense. Is my interpretation very much off?

Comment: @scaaahu: That's exactly right.  I even thought of using such a phrase -- maybe I should.

Comment: Nowak, not Novak.

Comment: Despite their idiosyncratic refusal to divide SEAS into departments, you can still classify the faculty into Applied Math, Applied Physics, Computer Science, and various flavors of Engineering. They aren't one big interdisciplinary research institute.

Answer (score 5):

While Pete's answer is correct in some sense, I think there's another important one.  To most people in the world, they will just hear "Harvard," "math" and "Ph.D." and think you're a genius; from the perspective of these people, these might as well be the same.  So, if your goal is to impress people who aren't experts, the difference between the programs is basically zero.

If your goal is to be successful in academics, then the overall reputation of the program is somewhat secondary; people won't care how venerable the program is if you can't show something significant you personally did.  The overall program is only important because of the networks it gives you access to (both of students and professors) and to some lesser degree the classes you have an opportunity to take.  That's maybe a slight exaggeration; having a name like "Harvard" on your degree will probably help you get people to look a little more seriously at you, but it won't do you any good if they don't like what they see.  Again, from that perspective, either program will probably serve equally well.

Comment: If your goal is to impress people who aren't experts, getting a PhD is an inefficient and quixotic way to attempt this.

Comment: Applied mathematicians themselves know exactly how good other applied math programs are. If you want to advance in academia, you need to impress other applied mathematicians. Going to an inferior Applied Math program at a very good school isn't going to fool anybody who really counts. (This is ***not*** to say Harvard has an inferior Applied Math program ... even if they're not in the top tier, they're still very good.)